# Shipping Address not displayed in the Paypal Transaction Details page

Tags: php, paypal, expressionengine

I am unable to get the shipping Addresses of my customers in the 'Transacton Details' page.
It's displaying the following message.

**'We have no shipping address on file'**

The issue mainly happens when users use PaypalPro (Direct Payment) option.

Can anyone help me in this issue.

**Note:**

This is my code corresponding to the DoDirectPayment Request.

class ProAuthorizeRequest extends AbstractRequest
{
    protected $action = 'Authorization';

```
public function getData()
{
    $data = $this->getBaseData('DoDirectPayment');

    $this->validate('amount', 'card');
    $this->getCard()->validate();

    $data['PAYMENTACTION'] = $this->action;
    $data['AMT'] = $this->getAmount();
    $data['CURRENCYCODE'] = $this->getCurrency();
    $data['INVNUM'] = $this->getTransactionId();
    $data['DESC'] = $this->getDescription();

    // add credit card details
    $data['ACCT'] = $this->getCard()->getNumber();
    $data['CREDITCARDTYPE'] = $this->getCard()->getBrand();
    $data['EXPDATE'] = $this->getCard()->getExpiryMonth().$this->getCard()->getExpiryYear();
    $data['STARTDATE'] = $this->getCard()->getStartMonth().$this->getCard()->getStartYear();
    $data['CVV2'] = $this->getCard()->getCvv();
    $data['ISSUENUMBER'] = $this->getCard()->getIssueNumber();
    $data['IPADDRESS'] = $this->getClientIp();
    $data['FIRSTNAME'] = $this->getCard()->getFirstName();
    $data['LASTNAME'] = $this->getCard()->getLastName();
    $data['EMAIL'] = $this->getCard()->getEmail();
    $data['STREET'] = $this->getCard()->getAddress1();
    $data['STREET2'] = $this->getCard()->getAddress2();
    $data['CITY'] = $this->getCard()->getCity();
    $data['STATE'] = $this->getCard()->getState();
    $data['ZIP'] = $this->getCard()->getPostcode();
    $data['COUNTRYCODE'] = strtoupper($this->getCard()->getCountry());

    return $data;
}
```

}

Comment: Are you using PayPal Payments Pro or PayFlow Pro?

Comment: Can you post a sample of your DoDirectPayment request?  I'm curious if maybe shipping details aren't getting sent to PayPal in that request..??

Comment: @andrew-angell Hi Andrew, I have added the code corresponding to the 'DoDirectPayment request in my question. Can you please check this and help me in this matter.  - Thanks, Sreenath

Comment: @Aaron, I am using PayPal Payments Pro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For DoDirectPayment you need to also include the `SHIPTO` variables:

```
public function getData()
{
    $data = $this->getBaseData('DoDirectPayment');

    $this->validate('amount', 'card');
    $this->getCard()->validate();

    $data['PAYMENTACTION'] = $this->action;
    $data['AMT'] = $this->getAmount();
    $data['CURRENCYCODE'] = $this->getCurrency();
    $data['INVNUM'] = $this->getTransactionId();
    $data['DESC'] = $this->getDescription();

    // add credit card details
    $data['ACCT'] = $this->getCard()->getNumber();
    $data['CREDITCARDTYPE'] = $this->getCard()->getBrand();
    $data['EXPDATE'] = $this->getCard()->getExpiryMonth().$this->getCard()->getExpiryYear();
    $data['STARTDATE'] = $this->getCard()->getStartMonth().$this->getCard()->getStartYear();
    $data['CVV2'] = $this->getCard()->getCvv();
    $data['ISSUENUMBER'] = $this->getCard()->getIssueNumber();
    $data['IPADDRESS'] = $this->getClientIp();
    $data['FIRSTNAME'] = $this->getCard()->getFirstName();
    $data['LASTNAME'] = $this->getCard()->getLastName();
    $data['EMAIL'] = $this->getCard()->getEmail();
    $data['STREET'] = $this->getCard()->getAddress1();
    $data['STREET2'] = $this->getCard()->getAddress2();
    $data['CITY'] = $this->getCard()->getCity();
    $data['STATE'] = $this->getCard()->getState();
    $data['ZIP'] = $this->getCard()->getPostcode();
    $data['COUNTRYCODE'] = strtoupper($this->getCard()->getCountry());
    //shipping information as you want displayed on transaction details. name is a single field.
    $data['SHIPTONAME'] = $this->getCard()->getFirstName() . " " . $this->getCard()->getLastName();
    $data['SHIPTOSTREET'] = $this->getCard()->getAddress1();
    $data['SHIPTOSTREET2'] = $this->getCard()->getAddress2();
    $data['SHIPTOCITY'] = $this->getCard()->getCity();
    $data['SHIPTOSTATE'] = $this->getCard()->getState();
    $data['SHIPTOZIP'] = $this->getCard()->getPostcode();
    $data['SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE'] = strtoupper($this->getCard()->getCountry());

    return $data;
}
```